# Adding a date variable to alter table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to alter temp table `#employ` by adding a `Comments` column which contains the sentence "employee will begin in" + the date they will join.

I tried starting off small by setting a fixed date to make the query work, but the @date variable is not returning 7/4/2014 after the sentence.

`DECLARE @date datetime
SET @date=start_date
DECLARE @sql varchar (1000)
SELECT @sql ='ALTER TABLE #employ ADD Comments varchar (200) DEFAULT ''employee will begin in' + '@date'''
EXEC (@sql)
SELECT Employee_ID,Comments from #employ`

The results from the query is the following:

```
Employee_ID    Comments
E901823        employee will begin in@date
R123441        employee will begin in@date
A390290        employee will begin in@date
```

Once I get past this step, I can try working to figure out how to assign different date values for each employee ID.

Desired results:

```
Employee_ID    Comments
E901823        employee will begin in 1/16/2015
R123441        employee will begin in 8/25/2014
A390290        employee will begin in 9/2/2014
```

Thank you very much, any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have join date as a column in #employ table? Also you need to update the column Comments with the string + date column right? Why do you want to use separate variable for each employ?

Comment: That is correct Kiran. the idea is that I can assign the exact date for all employee ID's. the temp table I am referencing contains the start date for each employee ID, but I would like to include it in the comments section. This way I aggregate other comments that do not have to do with employee start date.

Comment: Even when you get the quoting right, this won't work because the variable `@date` is not visible inside the the `EXEC`, Take a look at `sp_executesql` - you can pass variables into that. Can you take a step back and explain what you're trying to do as dynamic SQL should be avoided. Also.. there is no `SELECT` in that query so how are you getting a result? please post the full query.

Comment: I added the select statement. From reading other posts, I was under the impression the only way to add a dynamic variable to an alter table statement was by including `EXEC`? I would like the added option of showing the different start dates for each employee. Honestly, I'm not very good at this...and if this is a terrible way to go about it, I'm all ears... :/

Comment: It would be best to take a step back and explain what you are trying to do. Why does it need to be a temp table? Why does it need to be dynamic SQL? Where is the code that creates the temp table originally - why not put it in there?

Answer (score 1):

So what do you get? don't keep us hanging. I suggest you never define a data variable without a format. For example try this:

```
SET @date=CONVERT(DATETIME,'07/04/2014',103)
```

assuming the 4 is a month.

Comment: Apologies ElectricLlama. I will edit my post to include the results

Comment: was trying to get the correct formating. I posted the results

Comment: Now that I see your output, the advice I give is valid but will not help with your problem.